# What is the best way to copy file without blank characters in groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I have to do an exercise.I need to copy a file in an other one by erasing blank characters.I 've done the following.
Has anyone have a better solution ?

```
class Exercise4 {
   static void main(String... args) {
      Exercise4 ex = new Exercise4()
      ex.copyWithoutBlank("C:\\Users\\drieu\\tmp\\test.txt")
   }

   def copyWithoutBlank(String filePath) {

      File file = new File(filePath)
      File fileWithoutBlank = new File("C:\\Users\\drieu\\tmp\\test2.txt")
      PrintWriter printerWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWithoutBlank)

      file.eachLine { line ->
        println "line:" + line
        String lineWithoutBlank =  line.replaceAll(" ", "")
        println "Copy line without blank :" + lineWithoutBlank + " into  file:" + fileWithoutBlank.name
        printerWriter.println(lineWithoutBlank)

     }
     printerWriter.close()      
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: yes but I already have the solution.The point is to improve myself in groovy and find the expert solution.

Comment: My apologies, I jumped in too quick :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilise the `withWriter` method on `File` to open a writer, and close it when done:

```
class Exercise4 {
    static main(args) {
        Exercise4 ex = new Exercise4()
        ex.copyWithoutBlank('/tmp/test.txt')
    }

    void copyWithoutBlank(String filePath) {
        new File('/tmp/test2.txt').withWriter { w ->
            new File(filePath).eachLine { line ->
                w.writeLine line.replaceAll(' ', '')
            }
        }
    }
}
```